# Making a Lottery and it seems like I can't win

Tags: python

This is my code buy no matter how many times I run it all I get is you lost. What's wrong with the code?

```
import random

# Creates a number to count the amount of plays
count =  1;
# Creates a variable to store the amount of starting money
money = 10;
# Creates a variable telling you how much money you start with
startingCash = "You start with $" + str(money) + "!";

while (count < 101):

    # Variables for the lottery numbers
    lottery1 = random.randint(1,9);
    lottery2 = random.randint(1,9);
    lottery3 = random.randint(1,9);
    lottery4 = random.randint(1,9);

    # Lottery variables in one single variable
    lotteryTotal = (lottery1, lottery2, lottery3, lottery4);

    # Variables for the drawn ticket
    drawn1 = random.randint(1,9);
    drawn2 = random.randint(1,9);
    drawn3 = random.randint(1,9);
    drawn4 = random.randint(1,9);

    # Variable for the drawn ticket in one single variable
    drawnTotal = (drawn1, drawn2, drawn3, drawn4);
    # Variable that changes the money variable so the player has 2 less dollars
    money = money - 2;
```

it seems like the `==` sign gets ignored or acts differently. I wanted it to do the `if` if they are equal to each other.

```
    if( drawnTotal == lotteryTotal):
        count = count + 1;
        money = money + 5;
        print ("Lottery Numbers: " + str(lotteryTotal));
        print ("Your Numbers: " + str(drawnTotal));
        print ("You Won $5!");
        input("Press Enter to continue")
    else:
        print ("Lottery Numbers: " + str(lotteryTotal));
        print ("Your Numbers: " + str(drawnTotal));
        print ("You Lost!");
        input("Press Enter to continue");
```

Comment: If you can't win the Lottery, then your program works as expected ;)

Comment: To win you need to correctly guess with a probability of 1/9 raised to the fourth power; that's one win every 6561. Your code might just be trying to tell you something about the wisdom of playing the Lottery.

Comment: What about adding some output?

Comment: Your code works as expected it will just take a long long time for you to win. Try removing the `input` after `print("You Lost!");` and let it run. Eventually you will win.  As a side note, you shouldn't be using the semicolons at the end of the line. It is allowed but it is not very "Pythonic".

Comment: Try running it 9**4 times.  In that you are expected (not guaranteed) to win it once!.

Comment: Putting "solved" in a title is not acceptable here. If your problem is solved, click the checkbox by the answer that solved it. If it's none of the above, add your own answer, and click the checkbox by *that*.

Answer (score 4):

Your code *is* working... the results are just not what you expected.

The problem is that, to win, you need to generate the same random sequence of digits twice in a row. What is the probability of that?

The probability of repeating a toss of a single 1-9 digit is 1 out of 9. If you have two such digits, you have two 1/9 probabilities and their compound probability is 1/9 * 1/9, or 1/81. If you have *four* as in your case, you'll win once every 1/9 * 1/9 * 1/9 * 1/9 = 1/6561 games.

You tried "many times", but... did you try *enough* times? Even after *one thousand games*, the probability of winning at least once is less than 15%. Even after 6561 games, the probability of winning at least once is nowhere near 100% - actually it's closer to two thirds.

I modified it to only tell me the number of wins, and to only do so when indeed you do win (MarkyPython's suggestion). After some time, it tells me,

```
100 won in 686114 games; win rate is 95% of expected.
```

(The first win, by the way, was after 29172 games).

Answer (score 0):

Great explanation lserni.

Khodexian, in case if you are willing to increase the number of chances of winning you can simply take the numbers into account and disregard the sequence in which they were generated.

For example,

```
import random

# Creates a number to count the amount of plays
count =  0;
# Creates a variable to store the amount of starting money
money = 10;
# Creates a variable telling you how much money you start with
startingCash = "You start with $" + str(money) + "!";
win, lost = 0, 0
while (win < 100):

    count = count + 1;

    # Variables for the lottery numbers
    lotteryTotal = [random.randint(1,9), random.randint(1,9), random.randint(1,9), random.randint(1,9)]

    # Variable for the drawn ticket in one single variable
    drawnTotal = [random.randint(1,9), random.randint(1,9), random.randint(1,9), random.randint(1,9)]

    # Variable that changes the money variable so the player has 2 less dollars
    money = money - 2;

    if( sorted(lotteryTotal) == sorted(drawnTotal) ):
        money = money + 5;
        print ("Lottery Numbers: " + str(lotteryTotal));
        print ("Your Numbers: " + str(drawnTotal));
        print ("You Won $5!");
        win += 1
    else:
        print ("Lottery Numbers: " + str(lotteryTotal));
        print ("Your Numbers: " + str(drawnTotal));
        print ("You Lost!");
        lost += 1

print ('played {}, won {} and lost {}'.format(count, win, lost))
```

And I get a statistics like this,

```
played 40170, won 100 and lost 40070
```